# Setting up Pure-FTPd with admin/user permissions for same directory

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

I need to set up 2 Pure-FTPd accounts - *ftpuser* and *ftpadmin*. Both will have access to a directory that contains 2 subdirectories - upload and downlaod. The permissions criteria needs to be as follows:

- *ftpuser* can upload to /upload but cannot view the contents (blind drop).
- *ftpuser* can download from /download but cannot write to it.
- *ftpadmin* has full read/write permissions to both, including file deletion

Currently, the first two are not a problem - disabling /upload read access and /download write access for *ftpuser* did the job. The problem is that when a file is uploaded by *ftpuser*, it's permissions are set to 644, meaning that user *ftpadmin* can only read it (note that all FTP directories are chown'd to ftpuser:ftpadmin). How can I give *ftpadmin* the power he so rightfully deserves?

Answer (score 4):

Starting the process with a different umask (-U) flag set will solve the permissions issue. For example:

/usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -U 113:002 &

Note that each umask number is subtracted from 7 to get the final permissions:

113:002 results in 664 for files and 775 for directories.

Comment: We want this as the end result, but if your `pure-ftpd` uses the `/etc/pure-ftpd.conf` file, then [you should set the option there](https://serverfault.com/a/545401/50236). If your `pure-ftpd` uses the `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/` directory, then you need to [create a file `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Umask` and space-separate the umasks](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1840255) (e.g. contents: `113 002`).

Answer (score 3):

In your `/etc/pure-ftpd.conf`, set your Umask to 003:002.

This will set your permissions to `-rwxrwxr--` for files and `drwxrwxr-x` for directories. If you don't need execute permissions, then change the Umask to 113:002 which is `-rw-rw-r--` for files and `drwxrwxr-x` for directories. Pure-FTPd base umask is 777 and any umask subtracts from the base.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the sgid bit on the top dir, since group is already set correctly you're done.